# Is there any API to push DICOM images from md.ai to GCS buckets?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am looking for an API that can pull data from an MD.ai project to a GCS bucket.

Currently, we have an implementation where we have pulled annotated files from md.ai to a local directory (using project functionality of mdai.Client module) and then uploaded that JSON file from this local path to a landing GCS bucket.
So my main concerns here are:

1. Is there an API that can directly pull DICOM files from md.ai and then push them to the GCS bucket (instead of resorting to an intermediate step of downloading to a local folder)?
2. If not, can we pull the DICOM files to a local directory using the create_data_export_job() functionality of mdai.Client module and then push it to GCS bucket like mentioned above for annotated files?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate with [MD.ia](https://cloud.google.com/customers/md-ai) via [Cloud Healthcare API](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/resources/integrations).

As the MD.ia can be accessed as a DICOM store, you should be able to use The Cloud Healthcare API, to import/export data between MD.ia and cloud storage without the necessity of storing them in an intermediate location.

Once you enable the Cloud Healthcare API, and [configure](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/dicom) the MD.IA as dicom store then you should be able to import/export DICOM data between their MD.IA project and GCS bucket following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/dicom-import-export).

Comment: I could create a DICOM datastore. But the import and export options there, are only from and to GCS bucket. How do I import the data from md.ai to the DICOM datastore created?